# Alert shows up twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code contains two divs with the same *class* ("box") but different *id*s as follows:

```
<div class="box" id="inside1">
  <button>Hey</button>
</div>
<div class="box" id="inside2>
  <button>Hey</button>
</div>
```

Within each div is a `<button>` that is hidden. Once one "box" is clicked, both buttons appear. If the user clicks one of the buttons, the message "hey" should be pushed to an array (either `array1` or `array2`, depending on the button the user clicked) and that array should be alerted:

```
alert(array1[0]); // or alert(array2[0]) depending on button clicked
```

My code works fine, but the problem is, after clicking one of the buttons and getting 1 alert, if I click the other button, I get 2 alerts instead of just 1.

Here is my code:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

$('body').once('click','.box', function() {
  $('button').show();

  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  function x(array) {
    $('button').click(function() {
      array.push("hey");
      y(array);
    });
  }

  function a() {
    if (id == "inside1") {
      x(array1);
    }
    if (id == "inside2") {
      x(array2);
    }
  }
  a();
});

function y(array) {
  alert(array[0]);
}
```

And the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcg2wfgt/3/).

Comment: The event is going to bubble up from the buttons the the `.box` divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this.

```
function x(array) {
        $('button').click(function() {
          array.push("hey");
          y(array);
        });
      }
```

You are registering the click event every time you call x method, which you do on the click event.

You should move out the click event handler registration outside of your method. Something like,

```
$(function(){
 var array1 = [];
 var array2 = [];    

  $('button').click(function() {
      alert('clicked');
  });

});
```

Complete-simplified version of your code is

```
$(function(){

  var array1 = [];
  var array2 = [];

    $('button').click(function() {

      var id=$(this).closest(".box").attr("id");
      if (id == "inside1") {
          y(array1,'hey');
      }
      else if (id == "inside2") {
          y(array2,'hey');
      }        
    }); 

    $('body').on('click','.box', function() {
       $('button').show();     
    });    

});

function y(array,val) {
  array.push(val);
  alert(array[0]);
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xadeja/edit?js,console,output) is a complete working sample.

Comment: If I move the click handler outside my method how do I pass in the value for `array`?

Comment: I added a complete working solution to my answer. Take a look.